# Which design pattern to use to dynamically build form. PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I do not want to use already done library that builds forms in PHP. I want to write my own using design patterns. Im new to design patterns so I need to know which design pattern would best fit building forms dynamically in PHP.

For example so far i got something like:

```
 class FormBuilder {
    private $formName;
    private $formAttributes; //array('ID' => ?, 'Classes' => array(?,?) ...
    private $formStyle; //Css styling of form
    private Label $labels; //a collection of label objects holding bunch labels
    private Input $inputs; //a collection of input objects holding bunch inputs

    /* constructor to initialize everything */


   /* GET/SET methods for each of the above private variables */

   ....

   public function generateHTML() {
      //takes above information and builds HTML and returns html
   }
 }
```

now my problem is that i need to have an object for each label and an object for each input. Howerver i might need to have an object for  or other form elements. The best way to go with this instead of having classes for each would be to use **factory pattern**.

Can anyone suggest a design pattern for FormBuilder and patterns to use for Label/Input or how to combine Label and Input into one class that identifies it as label or input or textarea etc...

Comment: Why would you use different classes for the label and the input? You could simply set a "label" property on your input object. All you need to do is to use that property when rendering your control and its associated label.

Comment: I want to combine Input, Label, TextArea, and other form element classes into one so that i dont have to have bunch classes. Dont know which pattern to use

Comment: Since you mentioned 'build form' in your question. The best design pattern would be the Builder Pattern http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder/php/1#code

Comment: the `DomDocument` pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Builder Pattern. 
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder/php/1#code

Here is a very simple example.

```
<?php

class FormBuilder
{
    private $elements = array();

    public function label($text) {
        $this->elements[] = "<label>$text</label>";
        return $this;
    }   

    public function input($type, $name, $value = '') {
        $this->elements[] = "<input type=\"$type\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\" />";
        return $this;
    }   

    public function textarea($name, $value = '') {
        $this->elements[] = "<textarea name=\"$name\">$value</textarea>";
        return $this;
    }   

    public function __toString() {
        return join("\n", $this->elements);
    }   
}

$b = new FormBuilder();
echo $b->label('Name')->input('text', 'name')->textarea('message', 'My message...');
```

Outputs

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<textarea name="message">My message...</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks good, but this won't be helpful for dynamic forms. Dynamic forms like where a input depends upon other input element or a user dynamically add a new element.

There should be separate class for every element, through which the dynamism can be achieved. There should be a abstract element class which is extended by the input classes. Also, there should be a field class which holds a specific input object and it's label.

Will send the code soon .......